# Splitting a dataframe string column into multiple different columns in the same table

Tags: r

What I am trying to accomplish is splitting a column into multiple columns in the same table.

My data:

```
eventCategory   eventAction  eVentLabel
HomePage        Click        {"Name":"Ariel","number":"aaa"}
HomePage        Click        {"Name":"Dan","number":"bbb"}
HomePage        Click        {"Name":"Daf","number":"ccc"}
```

What i need:

```
eventCategory   eventAction eVentLabel                      Name    number
HomePage        Click       {"Name":"Ariel","number":"aaa"} Ariel   aaa
HomePage        Click       {"Name":"Dan","number":"bbb"}   Dan     bbb
HomePage        Click       {"Name":"Daf","number":"ccc"}   Daf     ccc
```

Answer (score 5):

Another `tidyverse` answer; this time employing `jsonlite::fromJSON` and `purrr`. This solution transparently handles additional columns embedded in the JSON and fills missing values appropriately.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

data.raw <- 'eventCategory  eventAction eVentLabel
HomePage    Click   {"Name":"Ariel","number":"aaa"}
HomePage    Click   {"Name":"Dan","number":"bbb"}
HomePage    Click   {"Name":"Daf","number":"ccc"}'

data = read_tsv(data.raw)

data %>%
    mutate(new_cols = map(eVentLabel, fromJSON),
           new_cols = map(new_cols, as_data_frame)) %>%
    unnest(new_cols)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   eventCategory eventAction                      eVentLabel  Name number
#>           <chr>       <chr>                           <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1      HomePage       Click {"Name":"Ariel","number":"aaa"} Ariel    aaa
#> 2      HomePage       Click   {"Name":"Dan","number":"bbb"}   Dan    bbb
#> 3      HomePage       Click   {"Name":"Daf","number":"ccc"}   Daf    ccc
```

Please note that `unnest` will drop all rows that have null values in the data. Consider this example:

```
data.raw <- 'eventCategory  eventAction eVentLabel
HomePage    Click   {"Name":"Ariel","number":"aaa"}
HomePage    Click   {"Name":"Dan","number":"bbb"}
HomePage    Click   {"Name":"Daf","number":"ccc"}
HomePage    Click   {}
HomePage    Click   {"Account": "010001"}'

data = read_tsv(data.raw)

data %>%
    mutate(new_cols = map(eVentLabel, fromJSON),
           new_cols = map(new_cols, as_data_frame)) %>%
    unnest(new_cols)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   eventCategory eventAction                      eVentLabel  Name number   Account
#>           <chr>       <chr>                           <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>
#> 1      HomePage       Click {"Name":"Ariel","number":"aaa"} Ariel    aaa      <NA>
#> 2      HomePage       Click   {"Name":"Dan","number":"bbb"}   Dan    bbb      <NA>
#> 3      HomePage       Click   {"Name":"Daf","number":"ccc"}   Daf    ccc      <NA>
#> 4      HomePage       Click           {"Account": "010001"}  <NA>   <NA>      010001
```

Note that we drop the row that has empty JSON (`{}`) in the original data. We also add a column for the new variable *Account*, and fill in `NA` values appropriately.

Finally, trying to run if there are blank lines on the JSON (e.g. (`""` or `NA`)) rows will fail; you need to remove those before passing into `fromJSON` with a `filter` statement. By example:

```
data %>%
    filter(nchar(eVentLabel) > 0, !is.na(eVentLabel)) %>%
    ...
```

Comment: I really like this solution, and it is looking great for a similar task I am on, however some of my JSON values are arrays, and when I `unnest` it duplicates the rows for each nested value - how would I modify that unnest step to concatenate the arrays into say a comma-separated string?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to split the string by `:` to extract the elements

```
v1 <- lapply(strsplit(gsub('[{"},]', ':', df1$eVentLabel), ":"), 
        function(x) {x1 <- trimws(x[nzchar(x)])
             setNames(x1[c(FALSE, TRUE)], x1[c(TRUE, FALSE)]) })[[1]]
df1[names(v1)] <- v1
df1
#  eventCategory eventAction                      eVentLabel  Name number
#1      HomePage       Click {"Name":"Ariel","number":"aaa"} Ariel    aaa
```

For the new dataset

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(gsub('[{"},]', ':', df2$eVentLabel), ":"),
              function(x) {x1 <- trimws(x[nzchar(x)])
              setNames(x1[c(FALSE, TRUE)], x1[c(TRUE, FALSE)]) }))
df2[names(res)] <- res
df2
#  eventCategory eventAction                      eVentLabel  Name number
#1      HomePage       Click {"Name":"Ariel","number":"aaa"} Ariel    aaa
#2      HomePage       Click   {"Name":"Dan","number":"bbb"}   Dan    bbb
#3      HomePage       Click   {"Name":"Daf","number":"ccc"}   Daf    ccc
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(eventCategory = "HomePage", eventAction = "Click", 
eVentLabel = "{\"Name\":\"Ariel\",\"number\":\"aaa\"}"), 
.Names = c("eventCategory", 
"eventAction", "eVentLabel"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))

df2 <- structure(list(eventCategory = c("HomePage", "HomePage", "HomePage"
 ), eventAction = c("Click", "Click", "Click"), 
  eVentLabel = c("{\"Name\":\"Ariel\",\"number\":\"aaa\"}", 
 "{\"Name\":\"Dan\",\"number\":\"bbb\"}", "{\"Name\":\"Daf\",\"number\":\"ccc\"}"
 ), Name = c("Ariel", "Dan", "Daf"), number = c("aaa", "bbb", 
 "ccc")), .Names = c("eventCategory", "eventAction", "eVentLabel", 
 "Name", "number"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
 ))
```

Comment: Thanks. but if i have few columns with diff values?  eventCategory eventAction eVentLabel Name number
HomePage Click {"Name":"Ariel","number":"aaa"} Ariel aaa
HomePage Click {"Name":"Dan","number":"bbb"} Dan bbb
HomePage Click {"Name":"Daf","number":"ccc"} Daf ccc

Comment: @ariel Sorry, I am not sure what you meant

Comment: For each column i need to split the string.

Comment: @ariel In that case, you need to loop through the columns of interest i.e. `lapply(df1[yourcolumns], function(x) strsplit(...`

Comment: @ariel You need to show an example regarding that.  I am answering only based on the input example you showed

Comment: eventCategory eventAction eVentLabel Name number
HomePage Click {"Name":"Ariel","number":"aaa"} Ariel aaa
HomePage Click {"Name":"Dan","number":"bbb"} Dan bbb
HomePage Click {"Name":"Daf","number":"ccc"} Daf ccc

Comment: @ariel Please update it in your post.  It is not easy to copy/paste from the comments

Comment: eventCategory eventAction eVentLabel                 Name number
HomePage Click         {"Name":"Ariel","number":"aaa"} Ariel aaa
HomePage Click         {"Name":"Dan","number":"bbb"} Dan bbb
HomePage Click         {"Name":"Daf","number":"ccc"} Daf ccc

Comment: I don't know why i can't paste table. in my comment there are 3 lines with diff values in eVentLabel  column.

Comment: @ariel You can `edit` your own post and update it there

Comment: Ok, thanks. but if i have 10000000 rows and i need to do it with loop.

Comment: @ariel If you have 1 tera byte data or so, you may have to use a different platform

Comment: Sorry. If i have 1000. Can you help me please with loop?

Comment: I don't know how.

Comment: @ariel  If it works for 3 rows it should also work for 1000 rows.

Comment: Can you please help me to do it?

Comment: @ariel It is the same code.  What do you want me to do?

Comment: I dont know how to do it in loop?

Comment: @ariel You said your dataset have 1000 rows.  The data you showed have 3 rows and the code works for it.  So, I think it should also work for the 1000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` approach

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr) 

    df <- structure(list(eventCategory = c("HomePage", "HomePage", "HomePage"
), eventAction = c("Click", "Click", "Click"), eventLabel = c("{\"Name\":\"Ariel\",\"number\":\"aaa\"}", 
"{\"Name\":\"Dan\",\"number\":\"bbb\"}", "{\"Name\":\"Daf\",\"number\":\"ccc\"}"
)), .Names = c("eventCategory", "eventAction", "eventLabel"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

  eventCategory eventAction                      eventLabel
1      HomePage       Click {"Name":"Ariel","number":"aaa"}
2      HomePage       Click   {"Name":"Dan","number":"bbb"}
3      HomePage       Click   {"Name":"Daf","number":"ccc"}

vars <- c("name", "number")

df %>% 
  separate(eventLabel, into = c("name", "number"), sep = ",") %>% 
  map_at(vars, ~str_split(., ":")) %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  map_at(vars, ~str_replace_all(., "[[:punct:]]", "")) %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>% 
  filter(name != "Name")

  eventCategory eventAction  name number
          <chr>       <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1      HomePage       Click Ariel    aaa
2      HomePage       Click   Dan    bbb
3      HomePage       Click   Daf    ccc
```

Comment: Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : could not find function "str_split"

Comment: do you have `stringr` installed and loaded?

Comment: Great. Why the script duplicate the columns?

Comment: Did this work for your data? I am not sure that I understand your question