# Splitting a single column in python into multiple separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a similar question than mine but the requirement was to do it in the "R" language. My knowledge of R is still in kindergarten stage and I cannot translate the answer from R to Python. So here goes.

I have a data frame with two columns - IAGSTNO and Quals:

```
IAGSTNO   QUALS
215299035 204212 BC:0 OT:VF #Subj:10 ||DI0430 BC:0 OT:VF #Subj:0
216034361 208086 BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:2 ||DI0800 BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:5
216138396 208382 BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:2 ||208082 BC:1 OT:WI #Subj:1
216139376 208383 BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:0 ||208388 BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:4
216149959 204179 BC:0 OT:HP #Subj:0 ||DI0420 BC:0 OT:HP #Subj:7
217028330 DI0800 BC:1 OT:HF #Subj:0 ||DI0824 BC:1 OT:HF #Subj:4 ||DI0825 BC:1 OT:HF #Subj:3
```

This was specifically extracted in this format to make it easier for the human audience it was intended for.

The data frame is about students that are registered for more than one qualification.

The QUALS column contains a maximum of three qualification groupings and the format is like this:
qual_code BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:3 ||
where

qual_code is the code of the qualification

BC:1 is an indication of the semester

OT:VF an indication if the student is full time/part time

hash (#)Subj:3 indicates the number of subjects the student is registered for the qualification.

The double pipe symbol '||' is the separator for the three groups of qualification

I want to do the following:

1. I want to create a new data frame with the IAGSTNO and three more columns (Qual_1, Qual_2 and Qual_3) with the string representing the three qualification attributes -  the full set of data with the STNO must be in this df
2. I then want to create a third data frame to split the three individual Qual columns into its respective attribute columns - the full set of data with the IAGSTNO must be in this df.

Even only a pointer will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance,

Phlip

The expected outcome:

Dataframe2 should look like:

```
Stno        Qual 1                          Qual 2                              Qual 3
217028330   DI0800 BC:1 OT: HF #Subj: 0     DI0824 BC:1 OT: HF #Subj: 2         DI0825 BC:1 OT: HF #Subj: 3
20522461    208383 BC:1 OT: VF #Subj: 2     208083 BC:1 OT: WI #Subj: 1     
206060165   208283 BC:1 OT: HF #Subj: 0     208NDP BC:1 OT: HF #Subj: 1     
207046409   208483 BC:1 OT: VF #Subj: 2     208083 BC:1 OT: WI #Subj: 1     
208039023   308030 BC:1 OT: VF #Subj: 2     208082 BC:1 OT: WI #Subj: 1     
210076615   308109 BC:1 OT: VF #Subj: 4     208083 BC:1 OT: WI #Subj: 1     
210082933   304004 BC:0 OT: VF #Subj: 10    304031 BC:0 OT: VF #Subj: 0     
210118008   308004 BC:1 OT: VF #Subj: 4     208085 BC:1 OT: WI #Subj: 1     
211112844   208282 BC:1 OT: VF #Subj: 6     DI0840 BC:1 OT: VF #Subj: 0     
211125334   208483 BC:1 OT: VF #Subj: 0     308109 BC:1 OT: VF #Subj: 1
```

Dataframe3 should look like:

```
Stno        1_Qual  1_Bc    1_Ot    1_NumSubj   2_Qual  2_Bc    2_Ot    2_NumSubj   3_Qual  3_Bc    3_Ot    3_NumSubj
217028330   DI0800  BC:1    OT: HF  #Subj: 0    DI0824  BC:1    OT: HF  #Subj: 2    DI0825  BC:1    OT: HF  #Subj: 3
20522461    208383  BC:1    OT: VF  #Subj: 2    208083  BC:1    OT: WI  #Subj: 1                
206060165   208283  BC:1    OT: HF  #Subj: 0    208NDP  BC:1    OT: HF  #Subj: 1                
207046409   208483  BC:1    OT: VF  #Subj: 2    208083  BC:1    OT: WI  #Subj: 1                
208039023   308030  BC:1    OT: VF  #Subj: 2    208082  BC:1    OT: WI  #Subj: 1                
210076615   308109  BC:1    OT: VF  #Subj: 4    208083  BC:1    OT: WI  #Subj: 1                
210082933   304004  BC:0    OT: VF  #Subj: 10   304031  BC:0    OT: VF  #Subj: 0                
210118008   308004  BC:1    OT: VF  #Subj: 4    208085  BC:1    OT: WI  #Subj: 1                
211112844   208282  BC:1    OT: VF  #Subj: 6    DI0840  BC:1    OT: VF  #Subj: 0                
211125334   208483  BC:1    OT: VF  #Subj: 0    308109  BC:1    OT: VF  #Subj: 1
```

I have tried "

```
df2 = dataset.loc[:,'IAGSTNO'].to_frame()
df2['Qual_1'], df2['Qual_2'], df2['Qual_3']= zip(*dataset['QUALS'].str.split(' ',2))
print(df2.head())
```

" which is one answer with a suggestion but this resulted into

```
     IAGSTNO  Qual_1 Qual_2                                     Qual_3
0   20073240  206015   BC:1  OT:VF #Subj:0 ||206017 BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:3
1   20522461  208383   BC:1  OT:VF #Subj:2 ||208083 BC:1 OT:WI #Subj:1
2  206060165  208283   BC:1  OT:HF #Subj:0 ||208NDP BC:1 OT:HF #Subj:1
3  207046409  208483   BC:1  OT:VF #Subj:2 ||208083 BC:1 OT:WI #Subj:1
4  208039023  308030   BC:1  OT:VF #Subj:2 ||208082 BC:1 OT:WI #Subj:1
```

which is not realy what I am looking for as indicated above.

I got the following example from "Chen, Daniel Y.. Pandas for Everyone: Python Data Analysis (Addison-Wesley Data & Analytics Series) (Kindle Locations 4984-4987). Pearson Education. Kindle Edition.":

"

```
# get the variable column 
# access the string methods 
# and split the column based on a delimiter 
variable_split = ebola_long.variable.str.split('_')
```

"
and changed it to

```
quals_split01 = pd.DataFrame(dataset.QUALS.str.split(' ||'))
print(quals_split01.head())
```

I have included the pd.DataFrame because I want to write to frame to a csv file with

```
with open('studMultQual_split1.csv', 'a') as f:
    quals_split01.to_csv(f, line_terminator='\n', index=False, header=True)
f.close()
```

This give me the following:

```
QUALS
"['DI0800', 'BC:1', 'OT:HF', '#Subj:0', '||DI0824', 'BC:1', 'OT:HF', '#Subj:4', '||DI0825', 'BC:1', 'OT:HF', '#Subj:3']"
"['206015', 'BC:1', 'OT:VF', '#Subj:0', '||206017', 'BC:1', 'OT:VF', '#Subj:3']"
"['208383', 'BC:1', 'OT:VF', '#Subj:2', '||208083', 'BC:1', 'OT:WI', '#Subj:1']"
"['208283', 'BC:1', 'OT:HF', '#Subj:0', '||208NDP', 'BC:1', 'OT:HF', '#Subj:1']"
"['208483', 'BC:1', 'OT:VF', '#Subj:2', '||208083', 'BC:1', 'OT:WI', '#Subj:1']"
"['308030', 'BC:1', 'OT:VF', '#Subj:2', '||208082', 'BC:1', 'OT:WI', '#Subj:1']"
"['208282', 'BC:1', 'OT:VF', '#Subj:1', '||208082', 'BC:1', 'OT:WI', '#Subj:1']"
"['308109', 'BC:1', 'OT:VF', '#Subj:4', '||208083', 'BC:1', 'OT:WI', '#Subj:1']"
"['304004', 'BC:0', 'OT:VF', '#Subj:10', '||304031', 'BC:0', 'OT:VF', '#Subj:0']"
```

with the individual columns but the IAGSTNO is missing and the results with all the double and single quotes and [] looks dubious.

Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Try to "show us" expected output and if you made any effort so far, share that too.

Comment: You say there is a similar question for R.  Can you link us to it?

Comment: See here, and `Series.str.split()`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

Comment: The link to the question in "R": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943147/splitting-a-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-different-columns-in-the-same

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the right direction?

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = '''\
IAGSTNO,QUALS
215299035,204212 BC:0 OT:VF #Subj:10 ||DI0430 BC:0 OT:VF #Subj:0
216034361,208086 BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:2 ||DI0800 BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:5
216138396,208382 BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:2 ||208082 BC:1 OT:WI #Subj:1
216139376,208383 BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:0 ||208388 BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:4
216149959,204179 BC:0 OT:HP #Subj:0 ||DI0420 BC:0 OT:HP #Subj:7
217028330,DI0800 BC:1 OT:HF #Subj:0 ||DI0824 BC:1 OT:HF #Subj:4'''

# Recreate the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))

# Create frame2 and add columns
df2 = df.loc[:,'IAGSTNO'].to_frame()
df2['Qual_1'], df2['Qual_2'], df2['Qual_3']= zip(*df['QUALS'].str.split(' ',2))

print(df2)
```

Returns:

```
     IAGSTNO  Qual_1 Qual_2                                      Qual_3
0  215299035  204212   BC:0  OT:VF #Subj:10 ||DI0430 BC:0 OT:VF #Subj:0
1  216034361  208086   BC:1   OT:VF #Subj:2 ||DI0800 BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:5
2  216138396  208382   BC:1   OT:VF #Subj:2 ||208082 BC:1 OT:WI #Subj:1
3  216139376  208383   BC:1   OT:VF #Subj:0 ||208388 BC:1 OT:VF #Subj:4
4  216149959  204179   BC:0   OT:HP #Subj:0 ||DI0420 BC:0 OT:HP #Subj:7
5  217028330  DI0800   BC:1   OT:HF #Subj:0 ||DI0824 BC:1 OT:HF #Subj:4
```

Comment: Thanks for the response: the result for the second data frame should be three columns with ||DI0430 BC:0 OT:VF #Subj:0 as data.